# C# Discord.net 1.0.1 - How to retrieve a users message

Tags: c#, discord.net

I am having a problem trying to receive/retrieve a message from a user. I am trying to compare the given message to a stored value. Here is my code:

```
                Random rand = new Random();
            int randomWord = rand.Next(rWords.Length);
            string text = Convert.ToString(rWords[randomWord]);
            var guess = await Context.Channel. //How do i retrieve a message from a user?
            if (gChar.Length != 1)
            {
                var message2 = await Context.Channel.SendMessageAsync("You can only guess 1 letter a time.");
                DelayDeleteMessage(Context.Message, 10);
                DelayDeleteMessage(message2, 10);
                return;
            } else
            {
                if (guess != text)
                {

                }
            }
```

the var guess is supposed to be the users input. 

The string 'text' is connected to an array with a couple of words in it so it can compare the 2 values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var guess = Context.Message.Content;
```

^ This will retrieve the message from the user.